# Quick Edit options not displayed

Tags: entities

Install Drupal 7.37

Download Ctools, Entity, Libraries, CKeditor, Quickedit, Navbar, Quickedit Tab

Add libraries: Backbone, Underscore, CKeditor, Modernizr

(enable downloaded modules)

Permission for "Access edit in place" enabled

===HOWEVER===

I don't see any Quick Edit options anywhere. Not in context menus, not in a deactivated block.

I tried just ctools/entity/libraries/quickedit at first. Then I tried with CKeditor but without Navbar and Quickedit Tab (and Modernizr). Then I added that set because it appears to create a shortcut button any time you're viewing an edit-in-place-able node.

There don't seem to be any module settings. But I'm not able to edit any fields in place. What am I missing?